# how to initialize nsmutablearray with nsarray

Tags: iphone, ios, nsmutablearray, nsarray, foundation

I am trying to initialize an `NSMutableArray` with the values of an `NSArray` but when I `NSLog` the newly created `NSMutableArray` all i get is (`null`), (`null`)... etc

I have no idea why this happening its super frustrating.

I set up `myMutableArray` in the header and `@synthesize` etc..

then in parserdidend delegate this is what I try to do.

```
- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{
    if (dataSetToParse == @"ggf"){        
        //Filter results (ISTOY = T)
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K like %@",@"ISTOY",@"T"];
        NSArray *filteredArray = [parsedDataArrayOfDictionaries filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

       NSLog(@"%@", filteredArray); //This prints correct details

        [myMutableArray setArray:filteredArray];

         NSLog(@"%@", myMutableArray); //This prints (null), (null)... etc

    //Use myMutableArray later...
    }
```

That pretty much sums it up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess `myMutableArray` is nil?

Also, you can do this:

```
myMutableArray = [ [ filteredArray mutableCopy ] autorelease ] ;
```

(don't add the autorelease if you're under ARC)

Comment: also, if `parsedDataArrayOfDictionaries` and `myMutableArray` are members variables backing properties, I think it's better to use property accessors, i.e. `self.myMutableArray`

Comment: That worked.. Why is it do you think the other that the way i was trying was not working??...

Comment: okay kinda understand what your talking about but what do you mean by backing properties?, I'll mark your answer correct as soon as the time limit is up :)

Comment: When you write `@property (...) NSMutableArray * myMutableArray` all you're 'saying' is "this variable can contain a reference to an NSMutableArray", but you still need to assign an NSMutableArray reference to the property for it to contain one. Make sense?

Comment: It's probably to complicated to explain in comments here.. `@property` declares the interface for a property, i.e. "instances of this class have a property called _x_", but it doesn't actually say how that property is implemented. Adding `@synthesize` creates a getter/setter implementation for a property, and also declares that the getter/setter store property's value is stored in a certain member variable.

Comment: so when you write `myMutableArray` instead of `self.myMutableArray` you are going straight to the member variable that stores the value for property `myMutableArray` rather then invoking the property's getter and setter

Comment: ahhhh yep I understand, I just hadn't heard it refered to that before.. thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 2):

As nielsbot said, or:

```
myMutableArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: filteredArray];
```

This already returns an autoreleased instance, if you need to worry about that.